# Not enough disk space to install Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: boot, 18.04, partitioning, disk-usage

I recently got a new Dell laptop and I'm trying to boot Ubuntu onto it. Currently I'm able to boot it with the USB plugged in, but when I try to install, I get the error: `You need at least 8.6 GB disk space to install Ubuntu. This computer has only 8.0 GB.`

How do I free up disk space? I also **don't** want to dual-boot, I'm okay with removing the Windows OS and just having Ubuntu.

Here is my output when i run `df -h`.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  1.8M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sda        1.9G  1.9G     0 100% /cdrom
/dev/loop0      1.8G  1.8G     0 100% /rofs
/cow            7.7G  425M  7.3G   6% /
tmpfs           7.7G   49M  7.7G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  8.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           7.7G  516K  7.7G   1% /tmp
tmpfs           1.6G   64K  1.6G   1% /run/user/999
/dev/loop1       91M   91M     0 100% /snap/core/6350
/dev/loop2       35M   35M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/818
/dev/loop3      141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/74
/dev/loop4      2.3M  2.3M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/260
/dev/loop5       13M   13M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/139
/dev/loop6       15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/45
/dev/loop7      3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/57
```

Here is my output when I run `sudo fdist -l`:

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 1.8 GiB, 1905045504 bytes, 3720792 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 91 MiB, 95408128 bytes, 186344 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 34.6 MiB, 36216832 bytes, 70736 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 140.7 MiB, 147496960 bytes, 288080 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 2.3 MiB, 2355200 bytes, 4600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 13 MiB, 13619200 bytes, 26600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 14.5 MiB, 15208448 bytes, 29704 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 3.7 MiB, 3878912 bytes, 7576 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 7.5 GiB, 8016363520 bytes, 15656960 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x40993ab6

Device     Boot   Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *          0 3899391 3899392  1.9G  0 Empty
/dev/sda2       3830956 3835883    4928  2.4M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
```

This is a Dell **Inspiron 13 7000 2-in-1**. 
I'm new to this, so any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your df is only showing the installer as sda? If new Dell you need to update Dell's UEFI and SSD's firmware. And then set drives to AHCI, not RAID nor Intel SRT. Only boot install media in UEFI boot mode, not legacy/BIOS/CSM mode. Shows installer with screen shots. Both BIOS purple accessibility screen & UEFI black grub menu screen
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI  What model Dell, some may need some other settings also?If erasing Windows be sure to fully back it up. Many come back later and have to run one program or game that only runs in Windows, or sell system with Windows.

Comment: Try running `sudo fdisk -l`, and see if the other drive shows up in the output.
You will probably need to tweak the settings in the BIOS/UEFI settings.
Try disabling secure boot, and removing any sort of locks or security settings from the drives that could be inhibiting the use of it.
In my experience, Dell stuff usually works well with ubuntu - what model of Dell laptop is it?

Comment: @Circo Edited my question to answer your questions.

Comment: Basically, I want to know how I can partition this to create enough space for the installation, or if I alternatively delete a partition to get that space (not sure if this is something that is done)

Comment: @Melissa Please read the first comment and follow instructions (and valuable advice). The internal drive isn't being detected by the installer and it's likely because the SATA mode is set to anything other than AHCI but also it may need the updates mentioned by oldfred, additionally of setting the supported mode, not instead. It has nothing to do with what Circo commented.